# Does Fusion drop columns?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I've got a CSV file with approximately 300 columns. Here's a sample of the columns:

[image]

The file is almost 100mb.

I've imported it into fusion tables using their GUI import through the browser. Here's what it looks like after import:

[image]

As you can see all the way to the right the column is getting cut off:

[image]

However, it does indeed recognize that there are more columns:

[image]

**How do I view the rest of the columns? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: why did you rollback, if I may ask? Unless I'm mistaken, or you're using the API for fusion tables (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/fusiontables/v1), this has no link to App Engine.

Comment: @Patrice sorry about that. i thought that perhaps this would be app engine related because after all it runs on app engine. but perhaps you are correct

Comment: no problem at all! we're all human :) I didn't want to get into a rollback war without posting a comment. I removed it again, because it is irrelevant to the app engine indeed :) If only I knew fusion tables a bit, I might be able to help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Tools > Select columns" to choose what columns to show. By default only the first 50 are shown.